# How to create a techniqueIcon from RGB bitmap in GMS 3.x

Tags: dm-script

In GMS 3.x we can create "Techniques" with customized techniqueIcon:

```
Image techniqueIcon := RGBImage( "Test icon", 4, 75, 75 )
techniqueIcon = RGB( icol, irow, iradius )
String techniqueName = "MyTechnique"
Object technique = CreateTechnique( techniqueName, techniqueIcon  )
```

How do I make the "techniqueIcon" to have proper transparency (i.e. alpha channel)? I tried the RGBA() function but the result icon still does not have the transparency as I desired. I can, however, create the icon in *.PNG format from an external application and assign it to a technique via the "Manage Custom Techniques ..." menu command.

Comment: The icon bitmap is stored in global tag group "WorkflowManager:Custom Techniques:[index]:Bitmap data". Is there a script command to get/set this special tag group "Bitmap data"?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe there is currently no proper way to set transparency to icons via scripting. DM scripting does not fully support alpha-values in RGB images.

---

---

---

However, your comment was interesting and send me experimenting.

The tag saved at the provided location, when watched in the tag-browser, does not seem to be a typical "array" tag, because those would display as `(values not shown)`. Instead, it shows as a long string.

The size of the tag (as given by `TagGroupGetTagSize()`) in bytes matches 4 bytes * width * height of the bitmap.

Assuming that each pixel in the icon has a byte-sizes values for R , G , B and Alpha, I'm guessing the "string" is just DigitalMicrograph's way of (mis)representing the binary array data, because it's not a known array form (aka image).

This led me to come up with the following script:

```
RGBImage GetBitMapFromCustomTechniqueIcon( number index)
{
    RGBImage bitmap 

    taggroup tg
    string path = "WorkflowManager:Custom Techniques:["+index+"]"
    if ( !GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupGetTagAsTagGroup(path,tg) ) Throw("Tagpath not found")

    number w,h
    if ( !tg.TagGroupGetTagAsLong("Bitmap height",h) ) Throw("Height tag not found")
    if ( !tg.TagGroupGetTagAsLong("Bitmap width",w) ) Throw("Width tag not found")

    string str
    if ( !tg.TagGroupGetTagAsString("Bitmap data",str) ) Throw("Bitmap data tag not found.")
    {
        number nPts = w*h
        if ( str.len()/4 != nPts ) Throw("Data length does not seem to match icon size")

        image imgR := IntegerImage("Red",1,0,w,h)
        image imgG := IntegerImage("Green",1,0,w,h)
        image imgB := IntegerImage("Blue",1,0,w,h)
        image imgA := IntegerImage("Alpha",1,0,w,h)

        // Browse and convert string
        for( number i=0; i<nPts; i++)
        {
            imgR[i%w,i/w] = asc(str.mid(i*4,1))
            imgG[i%w,i/w] = asc(str.mid(i*4+1,1))
            imgB[i%w,i/w] = asc(str.mid(i*4+2,1))
            imgA[i%w,i/w] = asc(str.mid(i*4+3,1))
        }
        imgR.FlipVertical()
        imgG.FlipVertical()
        imgB.FlipVertical()
        imgA.FlipVertical()

        bitmap := RGBA(imgR,imgG,imgB,imgA)
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

With this script, I'm indeed able to *read out* the stored icon and show it as RGB image.
However, I was less successful when writing the tags. The icons never update correctly, even after a DM restart.

```
void WriteCustomTechniqueIcon(number index,image imgR,image imgG,image imgB,image imgA)
{
    taggroup tg
    string path = "WorkflowManager:Custom Techniques:["+index+"]"
    if ( !GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupGetTagAsTagGroup(path,tg) ) Throw("Tagpath not found")

    number w = imgR.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
    number h = imgR.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)
    if ( w != imgG.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgG.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( w != imgB.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgB.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( w != imgA.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgA.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )

    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong("Bitmap height",h)
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong("Bitmap width",w) 

    imgR.FlipVertical()
    imgG.FlipVertical()
    imgB.FlipVertical()
    imgA.FlipVertical()

    // Create encoded data string
    string str = ""
    number nPts=w*h
    for( number i=0; i<nPts; i++)
    {
        str+= uncchr(sum(imgR[i%w,i/w]))
        str+= uncchr(sum(imgG[i%w,i/w]))
        str+= uncchr(sum(imgB[i%w,i/w]))
        str+= uncchr(sum(imgA[i%w,i/w]))
    }
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("Bitmap data",str) 
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing out on here.

---

---

**EDIT**

I'm getting *nearly* there when I trick the system and write a proper uint8 array of 4 times the image size using the code below:

```
void WriteCustomTechniqueIcon2(number index,image imgR,image imgG,image imgB,image imgA)
{
    taggroup tg
    string path = "WorkflowManager:Custom Techniques:["+index+"]"
    if ( !GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupGetTagAsTagGroup(path,tg) ) Throw("Tagpath not found")

    number w = imgR.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
    number h = imgR.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)
    if ( w != imgG.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgG.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( w != imgB.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgB.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( w != imgA.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )
    if ( h != imgA.ImageGetDimensionSize(1) ) Throw( "Images not of same size" )

    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong("Bitmap height",h)
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong("Bitmap width",w) 

    imgR.FlipVertical()
    imgG.FlipVertical()
    imgB.FlipVertical()
    imgA.FlipVertical()

    image array := IntegerImage("",1,0,w*4,h)
    array.slice2(0,0,0, 0,w,4,1,h,1) = imgB
    array.slice2(1,0,0, 0,w,4,1,h,1) = imgG
    array.slice2(2,0,0, 0,w,4,1,h,1) = imgR
    array.slice2(3,0,0, 0,w,4,1,h,1) = imgA
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsArray("Bitmap data",array)
}
```

The icon loads after DM is restarted.
However, the colors are all dimmed down and I don't really know why. Alpha, however, is working (including mixing values)

Comment: Thanks. Guess we need to stick with Icon without alpha transparency until there is a proper fix .